# React Selectable Fast: how to set and get checked items from a list of selectable items

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react-selectable-fast [link here](https://react-selectable-fast.now.sh/).

How to set/get `isChecked` prop provided by the library.

I have two classes, `Group` which contains the list of items, `GroupItem` which is the selectable item which is wrapped in `createSelectable` that is provided by the library, here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { SelectableGroup, SelectAll, DeselectAll, createSelectable } from "react-selectable-fast";

class Group extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            items: [
                { id: '1', name: 'item 1' },
                { id: '2', name: 'item 2' },
                { id: '3', name: 'item 3' },
                { id: '4', name: 'item 4' },
            ],
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // i want to set the the default checked items here...
        // before adding createSelectable > i've done that by adding
        //                                  checked (boolean) 
        //                                  for each item
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <SelectableGroup
                className="main"
                clickClassName="tick"
                enableDeselect
                allowClickWithoutSelected={true}
            >
                {/* I want to display the total count of selected items here*/}

                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        {
                            this.state.items.map(item=> <GroupItem key={item.id} {...item} />)
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </SelectableGroup>
        );
    }
}



// group item component


class GroupItem extends Component {
    render() {

        // props from group selector
        const { name, id } = this.props;
        // props from createSelectable
        const { selectableRef, isSelected, isSelecting } = this.props;

        return (
            <tr ref={selectableRef}>
                <td >
                    {id}
                </td>
                <td >
                    {name}
                </td>
                <td  >
                    {isSelected ? 'Selected' : 'Not Selected'}
                </td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
}

export default createSelectable(GroupItem);
```

By wrapping GroupItem with createSelectable, how to accomplish set/get checked items. `set in componentDidMount` `get in render`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish that by adding a property `checked` to the source of truth (items), and using the `SelectableGroup` handler `onSelectionFinish` which returns an array of selected components (refs)

```js
<SelectableGroup ... onSelectionFinish={this.handleSelectionFinish} />

handleSelectionFinish= (obj) => {

        let updatedItems = [...this.state.items];

        for (let i = 0; i < updatedItems.length; i++) {

            let item= updatedItems[i];

            let selectedItem = obj.find(k => k.props.id === item.id)

            item.checked = selectedItem !== undefined;
        }

        this.setState({ items: updateIitems })
    }
```